# Visual Studio 2015: CS0738 string property does not build when implementing Interop interface

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, com-interop

We have a .Net Solution which have classes that implement wrapper interfaces which inturn implement Interop interfaces which builds in VS 2010 and VS 2013 but not in VS 2015:

interop interface from metadata:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Interop.BlahNamespace
{
    [CoClass(typeof(BlahContextClass))]
    [Guid("Some Guid")]
    public interface BlahContext : _BlahContext
    {
    }
}
```

wrapper interface:

```
public interface BlahContextWrapper : Interop.BlahNamespace.BlahContext
{
}
```

implementing class:

```
namespace BlahCompany.BlahOtherNamespace.BlahNestedNamespace
{
    [ProgId("BlahNamespace.BlahContext")]
    public class BlahContext : BlahContextWrapper
    // This will not compile in VS2015 (2013 and 2010 are OK)
    {

        private string blahName = "";


        public string BlahName
        {
            set
            {
                blahName = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return blahName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error received is:

> Error CS0738  'BlahContext' does not implement interface member '_BlahContext.BlahName'. 'BlahContext.BlahName' cannot implement '_BlahContext.StageName' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IntPtr'.  BlahNestedContext   C:\PathToBlahClass\BlahContext.cs   8   Active